# Ajax request not working in IE10 when form contains file

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I used jQuery Malsup plugin to post form data in ajax.
http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#api

The form contains both text data and file data (an image upload field).
I used `ajaxSubmit()` to post form data. All data is processed in php in server site.

It works fine in chrome, FF, IE8, IE9. If i do not select any image upload field, ajax request works fine IE10. But when an image is selected IE10 shows pending in its dev tools.

You can test file upload functionality here.

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload

Comment: i could say that for IE8 and IE9, upload is done via iframe. you may see [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2) that XMLHttpRequest Level 2 support

Comment: According to malsup plugin when it sees  XMLHttpRequest Level 2 support enabled, is uses that. IE 10 has support for that. Then why it is failing?

Comment: I seen a different plugin ([Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/)) have the same issue. The solution to that might be similar to a solution for your problem. [Solution](https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/issues/758)

Comment: Do you have a doctype at the top of the page? Do you have a meta tag specifying how to render the page?

Comment: @yuvi Have you seen the malsup test page i shared at the end of my question? If you can run that example in IE10 you will get the idea what i am asking.

Comment: Yes I have, I tried running the upload using different versions of IE (using an emulator within chrome, not the real thing) and it failed on all of them. I'm surprised the older versions are working for you while the newer isn't (it's usually the opposite), so I'm just making sure it's not something with your own code (I'm taking it isn't)

Comment: @yuvi The malsup plugin code has nothing to do with my code. It shows the same behavior i am getting in my code.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the malsup developers directly?

Comment: Using IE11 developer tools to render the page with earlier releases, testing on IE versions 8 through 11 were successful. I am not able to reproduce your problem. Using [browserstack](http://www.browserstack.com) IE10 file submit was successful as well

Comment: The test works flawlessly.

Comment: @zeroflagL in browserstack?

Comment: I tested the upload functionality with an actual IE10.

Comment: @zeroflagL Can you also check this? http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic-plus.html

Comment: I bet you have enable some sort of "Compatibility" mode? or override Browser mode or document mode incorrectly?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using ?

Comment: This is why I mentioned the doctype. A broken doctype means your page will be in quirks mode where pretty much nothing ever works.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless whether the form is submitted via GET or POST, IE has no means to convert the file data into a string of text that can be transmitted to the server.

In order to perform a File POST without reloading the page, you'll need the following objects:
FormData, XHR.upload, File.files. "XHR" is the xmlHTTPRequest object, "File" is the DOM instance of a file selector.

You can fall back to a regular form POST if any of the above is unsupported:

```
if (!self.FormData||!xhr.upload||document.getElementById('file').files) {
  document.getElementById('form').submit();
  return;
}
```

Then the form data is fetched as follows:

```
var fd=new FormData();
fd.append('file',document.getElementById('file').files[0]);
xhr.open('POST',...); //complete your Ajax post here
xhr.send(fd); //the form data is sent here, with the file
```

Now that I have explained the mechanism of an Ajax file POST, it's possible that your plugin is already handling browsers that cannot have Level 2 XHR features. When you embed the plugin, make sure it's inside an iFrame. If you'd like to notify the main page when the file is fully uploaded, in the upload handler itself, embed a JavaScript call:

```
parent.doneuploading();
```

, where doneuploading is a JavaScript function that's defined in the containing page.

It's also worth noting that

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

in the form tag.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem where my success function wouldn't be
called on ajaxSubmit. I ended up looking at the jquery forms plugin
code and line 65 forces your ajaxSubmit to use a GET if you haven't
specified **form method="post"**. If your form is fairly large the get
will fail. So the work around is to use method="post" on your form
element.

Comment: OK cool, did it fix the issue? If so can you please mark this answer as accepted so others can make use of your post.

Comment: I meant form method post was declared form the start. So that is not the issue here.